# How to commit docker changes but select only a subset of changed files

Tags: docker

In one of my docker container, I installed a vscode extension. This is a dev container so I want to commit the change into the image.

When I run `docker diff container_id`, I got lots of files changed, but I only wan't to commit files in the folder of `/home/cccc/.vscode-server/extensions/`, how can I do that?